# Center text vertically but not horizontally in specified box imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to generate image from text. Requirements are: text left aligned, vertically centered, big as possible, max. resolution 1920x1080.

This is what I have:

```
convert -background white -fill black \
-font "fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf" \
-size 1920x1080 label:'Text \nloooooooooooooooooooooooooong text\nand another' \
-gravity West image.png
```

It works pretty well, but it doesn't center it to vertically.

Looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGHZg.png

But I would like it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JxKk.png

I could use -size x1080 and put that image into center of a blank white image using second command, but that doesn't make sure it is not too wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the gravity before creating the label....

```
convert -background white -fill black -size 1920x1080 \
   -gravity west \
   label:'Text \nloooooooooooooooooooooooooong text\nand another' \
   image.png
```

Edited to add: When a setting is supposed to affect a particular operation, in almost every case with ImageMagick the setting should come ahead of the operation. IM version 6 is somewhat forgiving in that regard, but as with your example, often the order of the command is important. IM version 7 is much more strict.

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of question, when someone knows the answer immediately, but I would spend days finding that one out. And it is so simple. Awesome. Thanks again.